# Maximum Number of times we can query an oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a piece of code as follows.

```
 Select * from abc_table where objectsnames="obj1" or "obj2"......"Obj1000"
```

Querying for 1000 objects.

Is there any chance for oracle timeout, if I call this query ten thousand times?

Comment: Yuck, really? 1,000 `or`'s? Called 10,000 times? What are you trying to do and how are you creating this query. There must be a better way.

Comment: please, clarify your question...show us the context of this query. how, when, why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to create a small table of object names and then join, something like:

```
create table objectnames
(
  name varchar2(100)
);

-- populate objectnames
-- could be from a file or another table or whatever
insert into objectnames ... 
commit;

-- query from tables
select a.* 
from abc_table a, objectnames o
where a.objectname = o.name
;
```

You could also use an EXISTS or IN statement, like

```
select *
from abc_table
where objectname in (
  select name
  from objectnames
);
```